# Flutter/Dart How to transform user uid from firebase in a variable?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, uid

I am trying to take the uid from Firebase and put it in a variable, to use it in another class, but the maximum I made until now is display the value in the homepage as a text. When I try to create `final String riderId = snapshot.data.uid;` in the homepage, it prints the error:

> The getter 'uid' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: uid

I already saw other questions in stackoverflow and tutorials on youtube, but none of them worked for me!

**My homepage:**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print(riderId);
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: AuthenticationService().authStateChanges,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
        // final String riderId = snapshot.data.uid;
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(snapshot.data.uid),
          );
        } else {
          return Text('Loading...');
        },},);}}
```

**My signIn button**

```
RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                context.read<AuthenticationService>().signIn(
                      email: emailController.text.trim(),
                      password: passwordController.text.trim(),
                    );
              },
              child: Text("Sign in"),
            ),
```

**My main.dart**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthenticationService>(
          create: (_) => AuthenticationService(),
        ),
        StreamProvider(
          create: (context) =>
              context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(...
```

**My authentication service page**

```
class AuthenticationService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Stream<User> get authStateChanges => _firebaseAuth.idTokenChanges();

  
  Future<UserModel> signIn({String email, String password}) async {
   
      var result = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      return UserModel(result.user.uid);
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use authStateChanges()

```
 Stream<User> get authStateChanges => FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges();
```

or

```
Stream<User> get authStateChanges => FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is still the same!

Answer (score 1):

The stream can emit `null` as a first event. So you should always access the `uid` after you do a `null` check or check if `snapshot.hasData`:

```
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print(riderId);
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: AuthenticationService().authStateChanges,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
        // final String riderId = snapshot.data.uid; // <~~ you'll always get an error in the first event if it's null
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final String riderId = snapshot.data.uid; // <~~ here should be fine
          return Center(
            child: Text(snapshot.data.uid),
          );
        } else {
          return Text('Loading...');
        },},);}}
```